# C++ Parameter Pack type expansion

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I was playing around with parameter packs in c++ and here's what I would like to achieve:

I have this 3 structs:

```
struct Base {
    Base(int x) : x(41) {}
    int x;
};

struct A : Base {
    A() : Base(41) {}
};

struct B : Base {
    B() : Base(42) {}
};
```

And I would like to create a generic function that returns a tuple with instances of the types specified, i.e.

```
magicFunction<A,B,A,B,A> == std::tuple{A(), B(), A(), B(), A()} 
magicFunction<A,B,A> == std::tuple{A(), B(), A()}
```

I tried to use template specialization to expand the types but was unfortunately unable to do it (I understand why it doesn't compile, just don't know how to fix it :) )

```
template<typename isEmpty, typename ...T>
struct ExpanderImpl {

};

template<typename Head, typename ... Rest>
struct ExpanderImpl<std::false_type, Head, Rest...> {
    static std::tuple<Head, Rest...> getValues() {
        if(sizeof...(Rest) > 0) {
            return std::tuple_cat(std::tuple{Head()}, ExpanderImpl<std::false_type, Rest...>::getValues());
        } else {
            return std::tuple_cat(std::tuple{Head()}, ExpanderImpl<std::true_type, Rest...>::getValues());
        }
    }
};

template<typename ...Empty>
struct ExpanderImpl<std::true_type, Empty...> {
    static std::tuple<Empty...> getValues() {
        return {};
    }
};

template<typename ...T>
struct Expander {
    static std::tuple<T...> getValues() {
        if(sizeof...(T) > 0) {
            return ExpanderImpl<std::false_type, T...>::getValues();
        } else {
            return ExpanderImpl<std::true_type, T...>::getValues();
        }
    }

};
```

Any suggestions on how to fix it? Also, is there a better way of achieving what I want?

The full code can be found here [here](https://godbolt.org/z/cW3rtJ) . Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Whereas there are simpler ways to create tuple, your way fails as both branches should be instantiated with regular `if`.

  `if constexpr` (C++17) solves that [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/d7tM9P).

  Notice that `std::tuple{Head()}` is also C++17 construct.

  C++11 would be `std::tuple<Head>{}` or `std::make_tuple(Head())`.
- Way to keep your implementation in C++11 would be to get rid of this runtime `if`, and use `std::conditional` to use either `std::true_type`/`std::false_type`

  ```
  template<typename Head, typename ... Rest>
  struct ExpanderImpl<std::false_type, Head, Rest...> {
      static std::tuple<Head, Rest...> getValues() {
          return std::tuple_cat(
              std::make_tuple(Head()),
              ExpanderImpl<typename std::conditional<(sizeof...(Rest) == 0),
                                                     std::true_type,
                                                     std::false_type>::type,
                           Rest...>::getValues());
      }
  };

  template<typename ...T>
  struct Expander {
      static std::tuple<T...> getValues() {
          return ExpanderImpl<typename std::conditional<(sizeof...(T) == 0),
                                                        std::true_type,
                                                        std::false_type>::type,
                              T...>::getValues();
      }
  };
  ```

  [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/PZ-W49).
- And you can get rid of `is_empty` wth different specialization:

  ```
  template<typename ...Ts> struct Expander;

  // Non empty case
  template<typename Head, typename ... Rest>
  struct Expander<Head, Rest...> {
      static std::tuple<Head, Rest...> getValues() {
          return std::tuple_cat(
              std::make_tuple(Head()),
              Expander<Rest...>::getValues());
      }
  };

  // Empty case
  template<>
  struct Expander<> {
      static std::tuple<> getValues() { return {}; }
  };
  ```

  [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/2eE8y4).

Comment: @Sc2slash: Way to thanks is to upvote helping answers, (and accept the "best" one).

Comment: Thanks :) I accepted your answer, but I can't unfortunately upvote as I don't have enough reputation

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is

```
template <typename... T> std::tuple<T...> magicFunction() 
{
    return {};
}
```

and you would call it like

```
magicFunction<A,B,A,B,A>();
```

And it will return a `std::tuple<A,B,A,B,A>`.  The way this works is `return {};` says return a value initialized (`T()`/`T{}`) return value, and the return value is `std::tuple<T...>` which is a tuple of all the template parameters

Comment: Hi :) I understand how to declare the function, I'm just unsure how to implement it, hence why I tried to use template specialization and was thus forced to wrap it in a struct. But you're right that the function itself does not need to be in a struct.

Comment: @Sc2slash This is the implementation.

Comment: You can see the return of the function here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9e4b474b9806f3a0

Comment: I see, you're correct of course :) But  how would you modify it if you didn't simply want to use the default constructors? What if I had A(int x), B(int x) and I wanted to create tuple {A(41), B(41), A(41)} etc? With the value 41 being hardcoded in the function

Comment: @Sc2slash If you're happy with using the same value for all the objects, you can change the return to  `return {T{value}...};`

Comment: Thank you. One more question, and I apologize if it's slightly off topic, but what if I wanted to use static functions of each of the classes to generate the tuple? I.e.
magicFunction<A,B,A> == std::tuple{A::getDefault(), B::getDefault(), A::getDefault()}

Comment: @Sc2slash `return {T::static_function_name()...};` is what you want

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be looking for

```
template <typename... T>
using magicFunction = std::tuple<T...>;

int main() {
    magicFunction<A,B,A>();

    // If no default constructors supplied.
    magicFunction<Base,Base,Base>(41, 42, 41); 
}
```